# Can `ivy-switch-buffer` add the current project's files (via `projectile`)?

Tags: projectile, ivy

I bind `C-x b` to `ivy-switch-buffer` and I've gotten used to the idea that pretty much all files I might want are in there (I use `ivy-use-virtual-buffers` to show recent files). But sometimes they're not, and then I have to quit and do `projectile-find-file` to open some file in my project.
Is there a customization for ivy to add the current project's files into the list used by `ivy-switch-buffer`? Like `ivy-use-virtual-buffers` but for projectile?

Comment: Does the function `ivy-set-sources` help? For an example, see its docstring and https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/issues/1132.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for! If you add this as an answer I can mark it as correct.

Comment: Are you sure it's what you're looking for? Note that the default action of `ivy-switch-buffer` does not call `find-file`, so you wouldn't be able to open these project file names directly; you'd have to call an action such as `M-o f` to visit the file.

Comment: @Basil You're right I'd say that OP is looking to bind what `ivy-read` does, then processing the choice depending on what list the choice was, etiher `find-file` or switch to buffer.

Comment: I see -- I already have my `recentf` files in there, via `ivy-use-virtual-buffers`. So sometimes it knows to open files. I think what I want is to expand that to include my project's files. (EDIT: Looking at `ivy--switch-buffer-action` it seems it knows how to do `find-file` on a virtual buffer.)

Comment: Looking at the code, looks like `ivy--virtual-buffers` would have to be modified to allow this. Right now it's hard-coded for bookmarks and recentf only.

Comment: Yep. If you want that changed, you can submit a feature request at https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/issues/